# Datagridview - Remove empty cells C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView2.RowCount == 1)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(11);
    }

    for (uint i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        string Name = PS3.Extension.ReadString(0x1234567+ i * 0x123),
        NPID = PS3.Extension.ReadString(0x1234567 + (i * 0x123)),
        XUID = BitConverter.ToString(PS3.Extension.ReadBytes(0x1234567 + (i * 0x123), 8));
        dataGridView2[0, Convert.ToInt32(i)].Value = Name;
        dataGridView2[1, Convert.ToInt32(i)].Value = NP;
        dataGridView2[2, Convert.ToInt32(i)].Value = XP;
    }

    for (int i = dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow = dataGridView2.Rows[i];

        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridViewRow.Cells)
        {
            string value = cell.Value as string;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                if (!dataGridViewRow.IsNewRow)
                {
                    dataGridView2.Rows.Remove(dataGridViewRow);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get it to delete all non used cells, it deletes all but one of them:

[image]

The one with the 00-00-00-00-00 in it won't. Anyone know why?

Comment: C# does not consider  00-00-00-.. as Null or Empty. I would suggest to say: `if (value[0] == '0' && value[1] == '0') dataGridView2.Rows.Remove(dataGridViewRow);`

Comment: I guess you can break out of the cell loop once you delete a row to avoid unnecessary looping.

Comment: @joemartin94 says index is out of range

Comment: @Bharadwaj I did break just didnt have it in the code on here for some reason but thanks